# Is is possible to take a derivative of a nonelementary definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Is it possible to calculate the derivative of a non-elementary function? $$ g(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} e^{-s^2}ds  $$It is not possible to reverse an definite integral by differentiation or allowed to evaluate a non-elementary function with the use of series.

Comment: I think you mean $\int_0^x$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that if $g(x) = \int_a^x f(s) \,ds$, and $f(s)$ is a continuous function, then the derivative of $g(x)$ exists and it equals
$$g'(x) = f(x).$$
So, in this particular case,
$$g'(x) = e^{-x^2}$$
which means the derivative exists and we know exactly how to calculate it.  This assumes that you meant to put an $x$ in your upper limit of integration.